# How to auto inject language by place pattern in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: javascript, java, intellij-idea

How to configure Intellij IDEA to automatically inject SQL language inside JS files for string template functions? 
For example i want to inject SQL for this code:

```
const query = SQL`SELECT * FROM table`;
```

In PSI Viewer i found that this is `JSStringTemplateExpression` node. 
How to configure place pattern for this PSI node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following places pattern works for me:

```
+ jsLiteralExpression().withText(string().startsWith("SQL`"))
```